# Program crashes when no value is entered

Tags: c#

I have created a program and have come across a problem. when I debug the program and don't enter a value e.g. a number and press the enter button a few times, the program eventually crashes. I am wondering is there a validation rule that could be put in place so the program doesn't crash when no value has been entered.

```
int userChoice;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Program().Welcome();
}


public void Welcome()
{

    Console.WriteLine("                       HELLO");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Main_Menu();

}

private void Main_Menu()
{

    Console.WriteLine("1). Welcome");
    Console.WriteLine("2). Help Facilities");
    Console.WriteLine("3). Exit");

    userChoice = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    Options();
}

private void Options()
{

    if (userChoice == 1)
    {

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome.....................");
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
    if (userChoice == 2)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Help.........................");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    if (userChoice == 3)
    {
        //if user selects option 3 the program will exit 

    }
```

Comment: Please provide crash logs if problem is crashing

Comment: you haven't pasted the full code

Comment: Use `Int.TryParse()` instead of `Convert.ToInt()`. This will try to convert the number and return a `bool` indicating if it was successful.

Comment: You don't need this `new Program().Welcome();` Simply call `Welcome();` in the `Main` function. I'm assuming your parent class, where `Main` resides, is indeed `Program` already.

Comment: @JasonEvans `Main` is a static method, while `Welcome` is not, so it is indeed necessary to create an instance of the class inside main.

Comment: @grek40 In that case make `Welcome` static also. Creating a new instance of `Program` in a console app is not the norm. I've never seen it done in the wild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This `Main_Menu()` method instead of yours. You will get smooth output.

```
    private void Main_Menu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1). Welcome");
            Console.WriteLine("2). Help Facilities");
            Console.WriteLine("3). Exit");

            string userChoiceSTR = Console.ReadLine();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userChoiceSTR))
            {
                userChoice = Convert.ToInt16(userChoiceSTR);
                try
            {
                Options();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Did not put any value. Please Select a menu: ");
                Main_Menu();
            }
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("Did not put any value. Please Select a menu: ");
                Main_Menu();
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much this helped a lot I am a student and i do this course in college.

Comment: is it possible I can make another validation rule for only number between 1 to 3 to be entered without the program crashing or exiting.

Comment: @Naz Yes it is, use if tests for the value parsed values

Answer (score 6):

Don't just parse, use try parse to validate if its a number or not.

Here is some shorthand's for integer types (whole numbers)

- long = Int64
- int = Int32
- short = Int16
- byte = (what whould be Int8 if it existed)

So just use the shorthand's they are a little bit more readable as they are more distinct.

```
int t;
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadKey(),out t){
//Do work with the number t
}
else{
//Handle a non numerical input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put an empty string into `Convert.ToInt16` it will throw a `FormatException`. Hence it is better to try to parse the input to an integer and let the user re-enter if something went wrong.

```
short s;
while (!short.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out s))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input invalid. Retry.");
}
```

(I have used `short` since you did in your sample code. Personally I would usually go for `int`)